# Using semver, should pre-release versions be based off the previous version number, or the next version number?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

Doing a pseudo-CD strategy for dev environments and we want to make sure all interim builds are tagged and versioned in a way that provides traceability but also conforms to semver so that helm etc doesn't yell at us and also I can sleep at night knowing I've bikeshedded correctly. I was thinking about the semantics of semver and how intra-release builds/versions might be tagged.

Assuming our process doesn't provide sufficient reliability for a "look-ahead" version (e.g. I don't know if our next release is going to be a major, minor, or patch increment), what would the best practice be for applying versions to builds between releases.

e.g.

Given last release of 1.2.3

Given a timestamp postfix for build metadata (e.g. a build might be called {version}-1668519441 )

Given that I don't know if the next official release is going to be 2.0.0, 1.3.0, or 1.2.4

Do I:

1. Apply the build number to the *previous* versionto generate the build version? 1.2.3-1668519441

   - this feels kinda yucky because *technically* it's the build of the next alpha version, not a build of the previous release version
2. Apply the build number to my *best guess next* version to generate the build version? 1.3.0-alpha-1668519441

   - this feels better, but we get burned if we guess wrong
3. simply weep, because the answer is "there's no one right answer" and now I have to make my own decisions?

   - ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reasonable smart* will be "modified 1" (because "internal builds" are just builds, for which we have to have "some id", which must just allow **internal
identification of it** and nothing more):

with something like `git describe HEAD` you'll get `1.2.3--14-g2414721`, `1.2.3-21-g975b`, `1.2.3-25-g2dc6` etc and any of these builds later according to (existing, I hope) Release Policy may become 1.2.4, 1.3.x or even 2.x.x (see idea of conventional commits and versioning of releases based on it), "just because..."

Answer 3 is daring and unequivocal version, but it's bad, because it does not answer the question and does not give at least a mediocre solution to the problem, but it's bad, because it does not answer the question and does not give at least a mediocre solution to the problem

Comment: Hmm - `git describe HEAD --tags` is a really useful tool, didn't know I could do that. Thanks!